# How to save data from JavaScript to C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I have problem with saving new record to the database, using C# controller.
Here is the JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function save1(input1, input2) {
    var lol = document.getElementById('input1').value + " " + document.getElementById('input2').value;
    alert(lol);
    $.ajax({
        url: ' @Url.Action("Saving", "LanguagesController")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { name: input1, level: input2 },
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Yess!!")
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            alert("Noooo : " + error);
        }
    });
    alert("End of function");
}
```

Here is my C# controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Saving(string name, string level)
{
    Language lan = new Language();
    lan.name_of_language = name;
    lan.level_of_difficality = level;
    db.Languages.Add(lan);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View(db.Languages.ToList());
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It just doesn't save it, I get message "error".

Comment: Is db your Entity Framework context?  Have you validated that your connections are setup properly?  Try writing a small unit test just to make sure you can write to the DB.

Comment: If I have Language as a parameter I don't know how to call this function in my JS code. Could you please explain more detailed?

Comment: @KevinRaffayI tried, everything is working well, so I can write/update/delete records in my db. I created it using Entity Framework.

Comment: Having you tried using the debugger and stepping through it?

Comment: You're passing the control to the `Saving` method instead of the value of the control..

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with what you have (but are you really expecting text back?), but this would be better:

HTML:

```
<a class="btn" data-url="@Url.Action("Saving","LanguagesController")">Save</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$('a[data-url]').on('click',function() {
  var url=$(this).data('url');
  var input1=$('something').val();
  var input2=$('somethingelse').val();
  save1(url,input1,input2);
});

function save1(url, input1, input2) {
    var lol = document.getElementById('input1').value + " " + document.getElementById('input2').value;
    alert(lol);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: { name_of_language: input1, level_of_difficality: input2 },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(result) {
        alert("Yess!!")
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Noooo : " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    });
    alert("End of function");
}
```

C#:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Saving(Language lan)
{
    db.Languages.Add(lan);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Json(db.Languages.ToList());
}
```

PS. difficality is not spelled correctly.

Comment: it doesn't help, I get the same error window, but thank you for trying. Could you tell more about new constructs or send a link about it?

Comment: Updated answer with newer constructs.

Comment: Updated answer with a better way of handling urls rather than placing them into the javascript.  This will allow you to move the javascript out of the view into an external file (which reduces the page size).

Comment: You could use the href attribute on the anchor as well, which would work well.  Also updated to expect a json result back.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're passing a `control` rather than a `value`

```
function save1(input1, input2) {
    var lol = document.getElementById('input1').value + " " + document.getElementById('input2').value;
    alert(lol);
    $.ajax({
        url: ' @Url.Action("Saving", "LanguagesController")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { name: getElementById('input1').value , level: getElementById('input2').value }, //changed from control to value

        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // define contenttype
    dataType: "json", //and the type you're expecting
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Yess!!")
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            alert("Noooo : " + error);
        }
    });
    alert("End of function");
}
```

And at server side, you must get your model as input:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Saving(Language lan)
{
    db.Languages.Add(lan);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return db.Languages.ToList();
}
```